# total noob with emulator problems

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

I am attempting to learn to code via flutter (I'm a total noob) and I am having some troubles with my emulator when I am trying to test my code. I am using Visual Studio Code, and when i try to boot my emulator, the phone will appear but the screen is completely blank.  the power button (on the emulator) is unresponsive and I get an error "emulator didn't respond in..."

I have literally been fighting with this for hours and I could really use a knowledgeable hand.  Can anybody help me troubleshoot, by chance?  I have searched here, but nothing matches exactly what I'm going through and I haven't been able to solve it yet.
[errors with android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gpvC.png)

My computer spec:
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G7 CPU @ 1.20GHz   1.50 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.7 GB usable)
Device ID   45818A1F-CFA5-4E12-AB9C-8192B75D2308
Product ID  00325-96713-52283-AAOEM
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display

Comment: I had this problem at first... Unfortunately, I don't recall how it was resolved!  (Sorry) What I do recall is that somebody on some forum guided me, and they needed all my computer specs. So maybe you should post those! It could speed up the process. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this probably seems obvious, but I seemed to struggle with this at the beginning since my course has me learning in VSCode, but I went into the android studio instead and I have deleted the old emulator and created a new one.   It's taking a while to finish loading, but the screen is operating and I think my problems are likely solved.

So I guess no, I never figured out why it wasn't working, nor did I get it to work.  but the end result is the same.

Comment: confirmed, this has effectively solved my issue and i am back on track trying to learn